# VHD with 3 partitions and 3 operating systems. How to split?

Tags: hyper-v, partition, vhd

Got a guy on the other side of Earth who needs a sole partition off of a vhd so he can do his job.  The entire vhd is over 490gb.  The 1 partition is about 80.  So I want to split the the vhd up into its 3 partitions.  A vhd file for every partition.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had to mess with this a while back. What I had to do was mount the drive, and it should mount the partitions as well as long as the partition table is in tact.

Once the VHD and it's partitions mount it will look just like a regular HDD/SSD.

Use something similar to disk2vhd to copy each to it's own individual drive.

From there you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something very basic to do that is risk free and you don't to mess with the partition tables or anything.

1. Copy the VHD 3 times
2. Mount each VHD alone
3. For each VHD, delete the partitions you don't want and only keep the one you need.